# Shrinkage as a percentage, $100\%$ or $\%$ in this formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions, percentages

I have a question regarding calculating percentage in the following:

> This shows the shrinkage as a percentage:
> $$
> \text{Saving percentage} = \frac{\text{SizeBeforeCompresseion} - \text{SizeAfterCompression}}{\text{SizeBeforeCompresseion}} \% \tag 1
> $$
> Example:
>
> $\text{SizeBeforeCompresseion } =\text{65 536  bytes}$ and $\text{SizeAfterCompression} = \text{16 384 bytes}$.
>
> The saving percentage is
> $$
> \text{Saving percentage} = \frac{\text{65 536} - \text{16 384}}{\text{65 536}} \% = 0,75 \% \tag 2
> $$

**Question:**

$0,75 \%$ isn't correct (I guess?), we actually have to multiply with $100$ to find the right percentage, i.e. $0,75\cdot 100 \%=75 \%$. So isn't it more correct to write $(1)$ as
$$
\text{Saving percentage} = \frac{\text{SizeBeforeCompresseion} - \text{SizeAfterCompression}}{\text{SizeBeforeCompresseion}} \cdot 100 \% \tag 3 
$$
?

Answer (score 1):

What you show here, and I assume is copied from something, $\frac{SizeBeforeCompresion- SizeAfterCompression}{SizeBeforeCompression}\%$,
IS NOT CORRECT!

It should be
$\frac{SizeBeforeCompresion- SizeAfterCompression}{SizeBeforeCompression}(100)\%$
A percentage is always a fraction of 100.  They forgot the "100".

In your example the percentage compression is 0.75(100)%= 75%, not 0.75%.